# SQL View use date between 2 dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing som data analysis and then I have a clear challenge, that i need some help for:

I've have table containing these:

```
VIN(Uniq Identifier for the car) - startDate - endDate - amountSpend
XYSBBNXZXDXAQ - 1-8-2022 - 30-8-2022 - 100.000,00
XCHEFFACSKNKN - 15-8-2022 - 30-8-2022 - 150.000,00
```

And then I would like to create a view like this:

```
Date - amountSpend
1-8-2022 - 100.000,00
2-8-2022 - 100.000,00
3-8-2022 - 100.000,00
.....
15-8-2022 - 250.000,00
16-8-2022 - 250.000,00
```

I'm running on PostgreSQL

Anyone there can point me into a direction of how to solve this in pos

Comment: what have you tried so far? what data type have your columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lateral along with generate_series:

```
select v.VIN, t.d, v.amountSpend from vehicles v,
    lateral generate_series(startDate, enddate, '1 day') t(d);
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f9c3d1c5b3990e13cd3fde68976dfd37)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was just the direction that I needed